# I'm creating a stored procedure on localhost PHPmyAdmin, but there is an error I cannot find

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have written this code but its shows error at the line 10. in my Editor line 10 is       `INSERT INTO employee(Name,EmpCode,Salary)`. Below is my code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `EmployeeAddOrEdit`(
    IN _EmpID INT,
    IN _Name varchar(45),
    IN _EmpCode varchar(45),
    IN _Salary int
)
BEGIN 
IF _EmpID=0 THEN
    INSERT INTO employee(Name,EmpCode,Salary)
    VALUES (_Name,_EmpCode,_Salary);
    SET   _EmpID=LAST_INSERT_ID();
ELSE
    UPDATE employee
    SET 
    Name=_Name,
    EmpCode=_EmpCode,
    Salary=_Salary
    WHERE EmpID=_EmpID;
END IF;
SELECT _EmpID AS 'EmpID';
END
```

This is the error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' at line 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHPMyAdmin SQL section,

> set the Delimiter to **$$** instead of **;**

and then run the query again.

See picture for reference
[image: Reference Picture]